# Starting ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

When I type `cfstatus` in a command window I get the message:

> could not contact ColdFusion application server on this machine

When I type `cfstart` I get the message:

> ColdFusion could not be started because its already running

Answer (score 4):

Did you install coldfusion Developer edition?

If so, what happens when you navigate to this in your browser?: `http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator`

If you get a login screen, everything seems to be working fine and all you need to do is start writing code in the wwwroot folder.

If you don't get the Coldfusion Administrator login screen, or you installed a different edition, please answer the following questions for me:

1. What Edition did you install?
2. What Version did you install? (assuming 9 at this point)
3. On What OS did you install it?
4. What did happen when you browse `http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator` if not the login page?

Comment: I do not believe the developer edition is installed
Yes its ColdFusion 9. 
It runs on windows server 2008. 
Navigating to the http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator results in a timeout.

Comment: Something must be if you got a message saying that Coldfusion was running.

Comment: I should mention, I typically login at http://localhost/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm thats also resulting in a timeout now.

Comment: Well, I was able to get it restarted by logging into Fusion Reactor and killing some processes that had been running for hours. Small victories...

Thanks

Comment: If you don;t want the hassle of running your own CF dev server you can always use www.cfmldeveloper.com

Answer (score 1):

The quick way to restart CF9 on a Windows Server is from the Services snap-in

**Start -> Run -> services.msc -> "ColdFusion 9 Application Server" right-click -> Restart**

Note that on rare occasions that CF takes a long time to stop and the restart event times out waiting for it to stop, you may need to wait a little longer and refresh the Services list to see when the Status changes from "Started" to blank, and then manually select Start.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens with ColdFusiuon, I don't know why, but the following steps worked for me

1. Open task Manager and kill all processes related to CF
2. start CF again by going to `cfusion\bin` and run `cfstart.bat`